# JSON file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am doing one project for a NGO. They do not have any database. For their address list of 150 and above, I have created an json file and the details are arranged as below. The JSON file :  "details.json"

```
{
"details": [
    { "Name":"            ", 
      "Age":"             ", 
      "Company":"         ", 
      "Address1":"        ", 
      "Address2":"        ", 
      "Address3":"        ", 
      "Address4":"        " , 
      "Pincode":"         ", 
      "Email":"           ", 
      "Fax":"             ", 
      "Phone1":"          "  
      "Phone2":"          ", 
      "Type":"            "  
    }, 
    { "Name":"            ", 
      "Age":"             ", 
      "Company":"         ", 
      "Address1":"        ", 
      "Address2":"        ", 
      "Address3":"        ", 
      "Address4":"        " , 
      "Pincode":"         ", 
      "Email":"           ", 
      "Fax":"             ", 
      "Phone1":"          "  
      "Phone2":"          ", 
      "Type":"            "  
    } 
]
```

}

The  type of address is = " **New, Regular, Old, Rare, Not_Respond**".
Can any body guide me how to design the JSON file with jquery? Also for each results, max ten address to be appeared on one page.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you mean by *"how to design the JSON file with jquery"*

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a question for Stackoverflow, but in the meantime I can point you to an [intersting tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/09/beginners-guide-jquery-based-json-api-clients/). It's pretty comprehensive.

> We use jQuery’s getJSON function, which, by definition, loads “JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.”